# How to make a mesh move in DirectX 10

Tags: c++, matrix, shader, mesh, directx-10

I am trying to create a flying tiger in DirectX 10. I have loaded in the tiger and the wing meshes but I want to make the wings flap. At this point I am just trying to make the wings move, not the tiger itself. I am new to DirectX and I am learning it as a hobby so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is my code:

```
void CALLBACK OnD3D10FrameRender(ID3D10Device* pd3dDevice, double fTime, 
float fElapsedTime, void* pUserContext)
 {
  //
  // Clear the back buffer
  //
  float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f }; // red, green, blue, 
  alpha
  ID3D10RenderTargetView* pRTV = DXUTGetD3D10RenderTargetView();
  pd3dDevice->ClearRenderTargetView(pRTV, ClearColor);

  //
  // Clear the depth stencil
  //
  ID3D10DepthStencilView* pDSV = DXUTGetD3D10DepthStencilView();
  pd3dDevice->ClearDepthStencilView(pDSV, D3D10_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0, 0);

  //
  // Update variables that change once per frame
  //
  g_pWorldVariable->SetMatrix((float*)&g_World);

  //
  // Set the Vertex Layout
  //
  pd3dDevice->IASetInputLayout(g_pVertexLayout);

  //
  // Render the mesh
  //
  UINT Strides[1];
  UINT Offsets[1];
  ID3D10Buffer* pVB[1];
  pVB[0] = g_Mesh.GetVB10(0, 0);
  Strides[0] = (UINT)g_Mesh.GetVertexStride(0, 0);
  Offsets[0] = 0;
  pd3dDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, pVB, Strides, Offsets);
  pd3dDevice->IASetIndexBuffer(g_Mesh.GetIB10(0), g_Mesh.GetIBFormat10(0), 
  0);

  D3D10_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
  g_pTechnique->GetDesc(&techDesc);
  SDKMESH_SUBSET* pSubset = NULL;
  ID3D10ShaderResourceView* pDiffuseRV = NULL;
  D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY PrimType;

  for (UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p)
  {
    for (UINT subset = 0; subset < g_Mesh.GetNumSubsets(0); ++subset)
    {
        pSubset = g_Mesh.GetSubset(0, subset);

        PrimType = 
        g_Mesh.GetPrimitiveType10((SDKMESH_PRIMITIVE_TYPE)pSubset-
        >PrimitiveType);
        pd3dDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(PrimType);

        pDiffuseRV = g_Mesh.GetMaterial(pSubset->MaterialID)->pDiffuseRV10;
        g_ptxDiffuseVariable->SetResource(pDiffuseRV);

        g_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);
        pd3dDevice->DrawIndexed((UINT)pSubset->IndexCount, 0, (UINT)pSubset-
        >VertexStart);
        }
    }

  // Render mesh2

  pVB[0] = g_Mesh2.GetVB10(0, 0);
  Strides[0] = (UINT)g_Mesh2.GetVertexStride(0, 0);
  Offsets[0] = 0;
  pd3dDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, pVB, Strides, Offsets);
  pd3dDevice->IASetIndexBuffer(g_Mesh2.GetIB10(0), g_Mesh2.GetIBFormat10(0), 
  0);

  g_pTechnique->GetDesc(&techDesc);

  for (UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p)
  {
    for (UINT subset = 0; subset < g_Mesh2.GetNumSubsets(0); ++subset)
    {
        pSubset = g_Mesh2.GetSubset(0, subset);

        PrimType = 
        g_Mesh2.GetPrimitiveType10((SDKMESH_PRIMITIVE_TYPE)pSubset-
        >PrimitiveType);
        pd3dDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(PrimType);

        pDiffuseRV = g_Mesh2.GetMaterial(pSubset->MaterialID)->pDiffuseRV10;
        g_ptxDiffuseVariable->SetResource(pDiffuseRV);

        g_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);
        pd3dDevice->DrawIndexed((UINT)pSubset->IndexCount, 0, (UINT)pSubset-
        >VertexStart);
    }
  }

  // Render Mesh3

  pVB[0] = g_Mesh3.GetVB10(0, 0);
  Strides[0] = (UINT)g_Mesh3.GetVertexStride(0, 0);
  Offsets[0] = 0;
  pd3dDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, pVB, Strides, Offsets);
  pd3dDevice->IASetIndexBuffer(g_Mesh3.GetIB10(0), g_Mesh3.GetIBFormat10(0), 
  0);

  g_pTechnique->GetDesc(&techDesc);

  for (UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p)
  {
    for (UINT subset = 0; subset < g_Mesh3.GetNumSubsets(0); ++subset)
    {
        pSubset = g_Mesh3.GetSubset(0, subset);

        PrimType = 
        g_Mesh3.GetPrimitiveType10((SDKMESH_PRIMITIVE_TYPE)pSubset-
        >PrimitiveType);
        pd3dDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(PrimType);

        pDiffuseRV = g_Mesh3.GetMaterial(pSubset->MaterialID)->pDiffuseRV10;
        g_ptxDiffuseVariable->SetResource(pDiffuseRV);

        g_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);
        pd3dDevice->DrawIndexed((UINT)pSubset->IndexCount, 0, (UINT)pSubset-
        >VertexStart);
    }
  }

  //the mesh class also had a render method that allows rendering the mesh 
  with the most common options
  //g_Mesh.Render( pd3dDevice, g_pTechnique, g_ptxDiffuseVariable );
  }

  void CALLBACK OnD3D10ReleasingSwapChain(void* pUserContext)
  {
  }

  void CALLBACK OnD3D10DestroyDevice(void* pUserContext)
  {
   DXUTGetGlobalResourceCache().OnDestroyDevice();
   SAFE_RELEASE(g_pVertexLayout);
   SAFE_RELEASE(g_pEffect);
   g_Mesh.Destroy();
   g_Mesh2.Destroy();
   g_Mesh3.Destroy();
  }


  bool CALLBACK ModifyDeviceSettings(DXUTDeviceSettings* pDeviceSettings, 
  void* pUserContext)
  {
    return true;
  }


  void CALLBACK OnFrameMove(double fTime, float fElapsedTime, void* 
  pUserContext)
  {
   // Rotate cube around the origin
   D3DXMatrixRotationY(&g_World, 60.0f * DEG2RAD((float)fTime));
  }


  LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
  lParam, 
  bool* pbNoFurtherProcessing,
  void* pUserContext)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  void CALLBACK OnKeyboard(UINT nChar, bool bKeyDown, bool bAltDown, void* 
  pUserContext)
  {
    if (bKeyDown)
  {
    switch (nChar)
    {
      case VK_F1: // Change as needed                
        break;
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You've posted too much code for anyone to quickly review, nor is it formatted for readability - with too many line-breaks and no indentation.

Comment: Read up on "Character Animation with DirectX 10 (or 11)"

Comment: I have removed some of my code and formatted it. Tried reading up on character animation but I still can't figure out how to do it.